# Store thread-safe global request specific data with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

A lot of the Rails app I work on depends on a few request specific parameters (`request_api_version`, `client_ip`, `device_id`, ...).

For now these parameters are passed along in each method calls. That's pretty heavy. Is there a thread-safe smart way to store this data somewhere to avoid passing them?

I though about global variables such as `MyApp.request_api_version` but I don't see this is as good practice (not thread-safe, ...).

Any other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr Use [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store).

Long version: threads in Ruby behave sort of like hashes (they respond to `[]` and `[]=`), and you can access the current thread through `Thread.current`. This lets you do stuff like `Thread.current[:client_ip] = request.ip` in the controller, then `client_ip = Thread.current[:client_ip]` in your model. This works great until the app server reuses a thread to handle a second request. Then chaos ensues and the universe is destroyed (or something).

The request_store gem handles this by wrapping every request in a special middleware that "cleans up" anything you store after the HTTP response has been sent. It's pretty trivial to implement this yourself, especially if you're only using a couple variables. If you want a more generally useful solution though, just use the gem.

Comment: Thank you plenty my friend!